# Sull'uso di "disanima" in questo brano

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

Nel libro *Maria Montessori. Una biografia* di Paola Giovetti ho letto:

> Ma proseguiamo nella **disanima** del contenuto de *Il Metodo*. I bambini devono fare ginnastica, possibilmente all’aperto: e questo insistere sulla vita all’aria aperta è un elemento decisamente innovativo per quei tempi e avveniristico. Una ginnastica che sia per il bambino come un gioco, ma che serva a irrobustirlo e renderlo agile. Importante anche svolgere piccoli lavori agricoli, curare le pianticelle, assistere ai diversi momenti della natura.

Ho cercato il vocabolo "disanima" in alcuni dizionari, ma non l'ho trovato. Ho visto però che esiste il termine "[disamina](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/disamina/)" che, secondo il vocabolario Treccani, ha questo significato:

> Esame attento, minuzioso: *sottoporre a d. una proposta, un’opera*.

Quindi, quel "disanima" nel brano precedente è forse un refuso? Dovrebbe essere "disamina"?

Comment: Penso sia un refuso...

Comment: Classico errore di ortografia: http://www.repubblica.it/online/lessico_e_nuvole/comari/comari/comari.html

Comment: @DaG: Potresti scriverlo come risposta?

Comment: Ecco fatto, @Charo!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scrivere o dire “disanima” al posto di “disamina” è un classico errore ortografico (se decidiamo di ammettere la categoria di errore in un'analisi linguistica), probabilmente influenzato dall'esistenza del verbo “disanimare”, quasi come se l'analisi approfondita giungesse fino all'anima della questione di cui si tratta.

Stefano Bartezzaghi evidenzia questa scorrettezza in una sua [vecchia rubrica](http://www.repubblica.it/online/lessico_e_nuvole/comari/comari/comari.html), affiancandola ad altre frequenti:

> ho appena letto su una rivista enigmistica l'ennesimo lapsus fra "disanima" e "disamina". Non lo vedo comparire nella mia pagina preferita del dizionario Zanichelli. Nell'edizione 2002 è la pagina 645, sotto la voce "errore". Ci sono segnati gli errori più comuni della lingua italiana, almeno secondo il giudizio dei redattori dello Zanichelli stesso. Lì si leggono parole meravigliose, come: accellerare, anedottico, appropiato, avvallo (nel senso di garanzia), areoporto, biricchino...
>
> Alcune di queste il mio computer si rifiuta di scriverle nella grafia sbagliata, si ribella ai miei voleri. Fra questi errori non è compreso "disamina", che molti scrivono "disanima". Ora: "disaminare" dovrebbe voler dire "esaminare con scrupolo", mentre "disanimare" è un'altra cosa: togliere l'anima, o l'animo, e dunque scoraggiare.